# Logging violations of rules in limits.conf

Tags: linux, logging, auditd, signals

I am trying to log the details of the programs that where failed due to the limit cap defined in the limits.conf. My initial plan was to do it using the **audit** system. The idea was to track the system calls related to limits in the limits.conf that where failed. However the problem with this approach is that , it is not possible to track the violations of cpu time, since that violation do not involve failure of system calls. In the case of CPU time , one thing happens is that the program which violated the cpu time will be delivered a SIGXCPU. So my question is how should I go about logging the programs that violated CPU time? Also is there any limits.conf specific logs available?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you really want to use [control groups](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/) rather than limits. For example here is how you can use it to limit [cpu usage](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html).